# Autoincrement id field in MongoDB and nodejs(express framework)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can i set an "id"-field in MongoDB-database with autoIncrement. I need unique numeric id. 
I know, that there's simple method instead of counting items...
my application made with nodejs and expressjs framework

Comment: You might want to consider an `ObjectId`. It's larger, but it will increment and be unique and can be efficiently created on a client.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [mongoose auto increment](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-auto-increment) plugin of mongoose for doing the same. It is quite helpful. You should have a look and give it a try.

Comment: Does mongoose-auto-increment handle concurrent requests ?? if yes then how ??